# Reported speech explanation

Tags: reported-speech

I need a very detailed explanation about reported speech. I'm confused about the tense change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of reported speech is

> A speaker's words reported in subordinate clauses governed by a reporting verb, with the required changes of person and tense (e.g. he said that he would go, based on I will go ).

To put it simply it means

> Reported speech is speech which tells the reader what someone said, but does not use the person's actual words

So it's like paraphrasing, but one tense back in time from the tense in direct speech (original sentence).

We use a "reporting verb" like "say" or "tell". If this verb is in the present tense, just put in "she says"

> Direct speech: I like ice cream.

> Reported speech: She says (that) she likes ice cream.

We don't need to change the tense in this case, though we do need to change the "person" from "I" to "she", for example. We also may need to change words like "my" and "your" in other cases.

But, if the reporting verb is in the past tense, then usually we change the tenses in the reported speech:

> Direct speech: I like ice cream.

> Reported speech: She said (that) she liked ice cream.

#### Some examples

| Tense | Direct speech | Reported speech |
| --- | --- | --- |
| present simple | I like ice cream | She said (that) she liked ice cream. |
| present continuous | I am living in London | She said (that) she was living in London. |
| past simple | I bought a car | She said (that) she had bought a car OR She said (that) she bought a car. |
| past continuous | I was walking along the street | She said (that) she had been walking along the street. |
| present perfect | I haven't seen Julie | She said (that) she hadn't seen Julie. |
| past perfect* | I had taken English lessons before | She said (that) she had taken English lessons before. |
| will | I'll see you later | She said (that) she would see me later. |
| would* | I would help, but... | She said (that) she would help but... |
| can | I can speak perfect English | She said (that) she could speak perfect English. |
| could* | I could swim when I was four | She said (that) she could swim when she was four. |
| shall | I shall come later | She said (that) she would come later. |
| should* | I should call my mother | She said (that) she should call her mother |
| might* | I might be late | She said (that) she might be late |
| must | I must study at the weekend | She said (that) she must study at the weekend OR She said she had to study at the weekend |

*`*` means doesn't change*

Occasionally, we don't need to change the present tense into the past if the information in direct speech is still true (but this is only for things which are general facts, and even then usually we like to change the tense):

> Direct speech: The sky is blue.

> Reported speech: She said (that) the sky is/was blue.

*Note the brackets `()` represent that you can use use or not use the word inside the brackets in the sentence - with or without the word is correct*

#### Tense table

| Phrase in direct speech | Equivalent in reported speech |
| --- | --- |
| **Simple present** | **Simple past** |
| "I always *drink* coffee", she said | She said that she always *drank* coffee. |
| **Present continuous** | **Past continuous** |
| "I *am reading* a book", he explained. | He explained that he *was reading* a book |
| **Simple past** | **Past perfect** |
| "Bill *arrived* on Saturday", he said. | He said that Bill *had arrived* on Saturday. |
| **Present perfect** | **Past perfect** |
| "I *have been* to Spain", he told me. | He told me that he *had been* to Spain. |
| **Past perfect** | **Past perfect** |
| "I *had just turned out* the light," he explained. | He explained that he *had just turned out* the light. |
| **Present perfect continuous** | **Past perfect continuous** |
| They complained, "We *have been* waiting for hours". | They complained that they *had been* waiting for hours. |
| **Past continuous** | **Past perfect continuous** |
| "We *were living* in Paris", they told me. | They told me that they *had been* living in Paris. |
| **Future** | **Present conditional** |
| "I *will be* in Geneva on Monday", he said. | He said that he *would be* in Geneva on Monday. |
| **Future continuous** | **Conditional continuous** |
| She said, "*I'll be* using the car next Friday". | She said that she *would be* using the car next Friday. |

#### Sources

- https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/reported-speech.html
- https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/

Comment: Why did you guys downvote? How can I improve my post?

Comment: This does seem to be a copy and paste job from your sources.  Did you write any of this yourself?

Comment: @JamesK Yes so far all of it is copy pasted, I am still editing it though to add other stuff written by me

Comment: @JamesK Is it alright if I copy paste the tables but paraphrase and add my own words to everything else?

Answer (score 1):

There are many questions about the topic on this site, such as the one I directed you to before.

Basically: Your friend says "I'm cold - can you lend me a coat?" You tell somebody else "Bill says that he's cold - I'm fetching him a coat."

Telling someone about it later on, you say "Bill said that he was cold, so I lent him a coat."

If what Bill said was something that is always true, you can use the present tense. "Bill said that Snowdon is the highest mountain in Wales."